# Can't get key of object that is numeric

Tags: api, axios, ejs

I'm working with an API that returns an array of objects. I can get all the keys, but two of those have numbers as keys, and I cannot get it. Give me an error.
I really dont know why I can not get it those keys.

Is there something different due to are numbers?

BTW Im using axios.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using dot notation, you should change to bracket notation to access properties start by a number.

The code below uses dot notation, it throws an error

```js
const test = {"1h" : "test value"};
console.log(test.1h); // error
```

Why :

> In the object.property syntax, the property must be a valid JavaScript
> identifier.
>
> An identifier is a sequence of characters in the code that identifies a variable, function, or property.
>
> In JavaScript, identifiers are case-sensitive and can contain Unicode letters, $, _, and digits (0-9), but may not start with a digit.

The code below uses bracket notation, works fine

```js
const test = {"1h" : "test value"};
console.log(test["1h"]); // works
```

Why :

> In the object[property_name] syntax, the property_name is just a
> string or Symbol. So, it can be any string, including '1foo', '!bar!',
> or even ' ' (a space).

Check out the document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)

Comment: Many many thanks. That worked perfect. I was trying to use dot notation inside destructuring, and it didn't work.  Now I'm using straight the object with this a works well.